# How to add the tab in html using pyecharts?

Tags: python

I have created charts using pyecharts, but I need to display the table in same HTML file, how to display this table to add the tab.add into main Tab?

```
import pandas
from pathlib import Path
from pyecharts import options as opts
from pyecharts.charts import Bar, Calendar, Tab, Pie
from pyecharts.charts import Pie

df = pandas.read_excel("Team_details.xlsx")
data = df.head()

grouped_by_names = df.groupby(by=['Name'], as_index=False).sum()[["Test Planned","Test Completed", 'Name']]
# print(grouped_by_names.head(3))

bar_chart_by_name = (
    Bar()
    .add_xaxis(grouped_by_names['Name'].tolist())
    .add_yaxis("Completed", grouped_by_names["Test Completed"].round(0).tolist())
    .add_yaxis("Planned", grouped_by_names["Test Planned"].round(0).tolist())
    .set_global_opts(
        title_opts=opts.TitleOpts(title= "Test planned vs Test Completed", subtitle= "In days")
    )
)



bar_chart_by_name.render_notebook()
tab = Tab(page_title= "Team Updates")
tab.add(bar_chart_by_name,'Task Report')
tab.render(Path.cwd() / "Project.html")
```

Comment: can you show us what you have created?

Comment: edit your question and add the code you have given

Comment: Now check the code! Help me out on this. Thanks in Advance!